# "Driver unable to load" message when connecting to an Oracle server from Apache Superset

Tags: oracle, apache-superset

I am trying to connect to an Oracle DB server from Apache superset. When I test the connection string it throws Driver unable to load.

I have even done installation of cx_oracle.

Comment: Can you debug code you cannot see?  Of course not.  And neither can anyone else.  Also, error messages usually contain useful information, but only when we see the entire, exact message and not your condensed paraphrase of it.

Answer (score 0):

The most common problem when trying to connect apache superset to an Oracle DB is that apart from the cx_oracle library in the python part, you need to install the Oracle client library in the machine with superset. Refer to Oracle documentation and other Stackoverflow threads on how to do this.